# Inverting a dictionary when some of the original values are identical

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary called `word_counter_dictionary` that counts how many words are in the document in the form `{'word' : number}`. For example, the word "secondly" appears one time, so the key/value pair would be `{'secondly' : 1}`. I want to make an inverted list so that the numbers will become keys and the words will become the values for those keys so I can then graph the top 25 most used words. I saw somewhere where the `setdefault()` function might come in handy, but regardless I cannot use it because so far in the class I am in we have only covered `get()`.

```
inverted_dictionary = {}
for key in word_counter_dictionary:
    new_key = word_counter_dictionary[key]
    inverted_dictionary[new_key] = word_counter_dictionary.get(new_key, '') + str(key)   
    inverted_dictionary
```

So far, using this method above, it works fine until it reaches another word with the same value. For example, the word `"saves"` also appears once in the document, so Python will add the new key/value pair just fine. BUT it erases the `{1 : 'secondly'}` with the new pair so that only `{1 : 'saves'}` is in the dictionary.

So, bottom line, my goal is to get ALL of the words and their respective number of repetitions in this new dictionary called `inverted_dictionary`.

Comment: Your problem, as I think you realize, is that a dictionary can't have multiple values for one key, such as the number 1. However, it could have, as the single value, a _collection_ of other values.

Comment: OK, you want to look through the dictionary `keys` every time before you try to do this. If this words exists there already just increase the count for out. Rinse&repeat *ad infinitum*.

Comment: If all you want to do is extract the keys with the 25 biggest values you don't have to create this inverted dict first.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Pardon my novice expertise haha I'm a beginner. So, how can I extract the keys AND their values for the 25 biggest values so that I can graph it in a histogram without creating an inverted dictionary?

Comment: @UnworthyToast I posted an answer that takes another approach. I'm also a novice, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

A [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is perfect for this

```
word_counter_dictionary = {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3, 'fourth':2}
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in word_counter_dictionary.iteritems():
    d[value].append(key)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['first'], 2: ['second', 'fourth'], 3: ['third']})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is convert the value in a list of words with the same key:

```
word_counter_dictionary = {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3, 'fourth':2}

inverted_dictionary = {}
for key in word_counter_dictionary:
    new_key = word_counter_dictionary[key]
    if new_key in inverted_dictionary:
        inverted_dictionary[new_key].append(str(key))
    else:
        inverted_dictionary[new_key] = [str(key)]

print inverted_dictionary

>>> {1: ['first'], 2: ['second', 'fourth'], 3: ['third']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dicts do NOT allow repeated keys, so you can't use a simple dictionary to store multiple elements with the same key (`1` in your case). For your example, I'd rather have a `list` as the value of your *inverted* dictionary, and store in that list the words that share the number of appearances, like:

```
inverted_dictionary = {}
for key in word_counter_dictionary:
    new_key = word_counter_dictionary[key]
    if new_key in inverted_dictionary:
        inverted_dictionary[new_key].append(key)
    else:
        inverted_dictionary[new_key] = [key]
```

In order to get the 25 most repeated words, you should iterate through the (sorted) keys in the `inverted_dictionary` and store the words:

```
common_words = []
for key in sorted(inverted_dictionary.keys(), reverse=True):
    if len(common_words) < 25:
        common_words.extend(inverted_dictionary[key])
    else: 
        break

common_words = common_words[:25] # In case there are more than 25 words
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! Now, how would I grab only the largest 25 keys so that I can graph them? I can't think of a way besides a slice operation but obviously I cannot do that for a dictionary :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that doesn't "invert" the dictionary:

```
>>> import operator
>>> A = {'a':10, 'b':843, 'c': 39, 'd': 10}
>>> B = sorted(A.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> B
[('b', 843), ('c', 39), ('a', 10), ('d', 10)]
```

Instead, it creates a list that is sorted, highest to lowest, by value.

To get the top 25, you simply slice it: `B[:25]`.

And here's one way to get the keys and values separated (after putting them into a list of tuples):

```
>>> [x[0] for x in B]
['b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
>>> [x[1] for x in B]
[843, 39, 10, 10]
```

or

```
>>> C, D = zip(*B)
>>> C
('b', 'c', 'a', 'd')
>>> D
(843, 39, 10, 10)
```

Note that if you only want to extract the keys or the values (and not both) you should have done so earlier. This is just examples of how to handle the tuple list.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the largest elements of some dataset an inverted dictionary might not be the best data structure.

Either put the items in a sorted list (example assumes you want to get to two most frequent words):

```
word_counter_dictionary = {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3, 'fourth':2}
counter_word_list = sorted((count, word) for word, count in word_counter_dictionary.items())
```

Result:

```
>>> print(counter_word_list[-2:])
[(2, 'second'), (3, 'third')]
```

Or use Python's included batteries (`heapq.nlargest` in this case):

```
import heapq, operator
print(heapq.nlargest(2, word_counter_dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Result:

```
[('third', 3), ('second', 2)]
```